# Julia Dataframes Groupby chain using combine

Tags: dataframe, julia

i'm trying to do the following :

For each columns i want to groupby the key with the column , count the number of occurence and keep only the biggest occurence by key (i don't want to keep the amount of occurence , just the value that correspond to it ).
I have many columns to groupby with keys in a row and i wanted to know if there is a way to chain it together.

Here is an example :

```
│ Row      │ KEY                              │ A             │
│          │ String                           │ String        │
├──────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ 1        │ 44473                            │ ROCK          │
│ 2        │ 4f4ef                            │ CLASSICAL     │
│ 3        │ 0b8bd                            │ POP           │
│ 4        │ 57c94                            │ POP           │
│ 5        │ a7070                            │ RAP - HIP HOP │
│ 6        │ 1d9a3                            │ JAZZ          │
│ 7        │ 947fd                            │ POP           │
```

Here i do :

```
 per_key =  DataFrames.groupby(test, [:KEY, :A])
 combine(per_key, nrow => :A)
```

which gives me :

```
│ Row  │ KEY                              │ A                  │ nrow  │
│      │ String                           │ String             │ Int64 │
├──────┼──────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼───────┤
│ 1    │ 44473ff                          │ ROCK               │ 2     │
│ 2    │ 4f4effc                          │ CLASSICAL          │ 12    │
│ 3    │ 0b8bd64                          │ POP                │ 2     │
│ 4    │ 57c94f5                          │ POP                │ 2     │
│ 5    │ a7070e4                          │ RAP - HIP HOP      │ 1     │
│ 6    │ 1d9a3c7                          │ JAZZ               │ 1     │
```

How do i do for each KEY , get the max "nrow" and keep the corresponding value in "A".

I have to do it with many other columns one by one also.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% what you wanted, but I assume this is the thing that you are looking for:

```
julia> using DataFrames, StatsBase

julia> df = DataFrame(key=rand(1:10, 10^6),
                      A = rand(1:10, 10^6),
                      B = rand(1:10, 10^6),
                      C = rand(1:10, 10^6));

julia> gdf = groupby(df, :key);

julia> combine(gdf, valuecols(gdf) .=>
                    (x -> last(maximum(reverse, countmap(x)))) .=>
                    valuecols(gdf))
10×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ key   │ A     │ B     │ C     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 8     │ 8     │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 10    │ 1     │ 2     │ 9     │
│ 3   │ 2     │ 6     │ 7     │ 3     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 10    │ 7     │ 4     │
│ 5   │ 3     │ 8     │ 3     │ 1     │
│ 6   │ 7     │ 9     │ 7     │ 8     │
│ 7   │ 8     │ 2     │ 3     │ 2     │
│ 8   │ 5     │ 4     │ 3     │ 9     │
│ 9   │ 9     │ 3     │ 2     │ 10    │
│ 10  │ 6     │ 8     │ 4     │ 10    │
```

(on master you can add `renamecols=false` kwarg to avoid last `.=> valuecols(gdf)`).

The key function here is `countmap` which gives you counts of occurences of different values in a vector, e.g.:

```
julia> countmap(gdf[1].A)
Dict{Int64,Int64} with 10 entries:
  7  => 10028
  4  => 10130
  9  => 10007
  10 => 9841
  2  => 10090
  3  => 9985
  5  => 10022
  8  => 10262
  6  => 10103
  1  => 10128
```

the rest is just a wrapper around it. You need `reverse` to change `key => value` to `value => key` order to make sure `maximum` picks a right group (note that your problem will not have a unique solution if there are two groups with the same count), and then we use `last` to extract the group (as you did not want to keep the count).

EDIT:

Now I realized that `argmax` works for dictionaries so you can just write:

```
julia> combine(gdf, valuecols(gdf) .=>
                    argmax∘countmap .=>
                    valuecols(gdf))
10×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ key   │ A     │ B     │ C     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 8     │ 8     │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 10    │ 1     │ 2     │ 9     │
│ 3   │ 2     │ 6     │ 7     │ 3     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 10    │ 7     │ 4     │
│ 5   │ 3     │ 8     │ 3     │ 1     │
│ 6   │ 7     │ 9     │ 7     │ 8     │
│ 7   │ 8     │ 2     │ 3     │ 2     │
│ 8   │ 5     │ 4     │ 3     │ 9     │
│ 9   │ 9     │ 3     │ 2     │ 10    │
│ 10  │ 6     │ 8     │ 4     │ 10    │
```

Comment: Thank you , that's what i was searching .
Im trying to do another one , but here one of the column is the average of frequency of dates.
I have dates (many rows with same key), i want to apply a diff and then a mean on it 
I tried this :  combine(df, :DATE .=> diff .=> mean) but doesn't work . Can you tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the ∘ for ?

Comment: It is function composition: `(f ∘ g)(args...)` means `f(g(args...))`.